# onelogin api with php curl 401 unauthorized

Tags: php, json, curl, lampp, onelogin

I have a simple curl request to the onelogin api written in PHP. The request works fine with my parameters from my terminal and I am able to login my user, however the php version I run on server, generates access token but then gives a 401 error when i try any GET or POST requests. Ive tried all sorts of curl parameters. An html form submits to this php page hosted on a lampp stack. Does not seem to work. Below is the php script with a simple GET request. Would really appreciate any help on this:

```
<?php

//form will post these variables for post request
//$username = $_POST['uname'];
//$password = $_POST['pwd'];

$data = array("grant_type" => "client_credentials");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: client_id:XXX, client_secret:XXX",
    "Content-Type: application/json")
);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

//parsse out bearer token and set header
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$a_token = $json['data'][0]['access_token'];
$bearer_token = "Authorization: bearer: ". $a_token;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($bearer_token));

//execute 
$result2 = curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result2;
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but my best bet is that you haven't configured the bearer token header correctly (OneLogin doesn't like the space after the final ':' and is interpreting it as part of the bearer token)

So you should try

```
$bearer_token = "Authorization: Bearer:". $a_token; // no space after Bearer:
```

Comment: Then it's a php coding issue, I'm guessing.
At this point it looks more like a coding error than a problem with the API.

Best bet would be to 

a) inspect the bearer token you're getting back just to make sure it is being parsed out correctly

b) Make a new request object for the 2nd request e.g.

$ch2 = curl_init('https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users');

Since you're reusing the first request, it might still be set to do a POST (that 2nd endpoint is a GET) and might be cluttered with other options left over from that first request. Better to start with a clean slate

Comment: a) Yes..tried that...its being parsed and sent into the next function correctly. b) Created new request object $ch2.....Note this also fails for my POST requests!.......none worked!

Comment: If you could do me a favor and reach out to Devsupport@onelogin.com we can take a look at the specific requests you're making - at the end of the day I'm convinced there's something about the way the bearer token is being sent that's causing the problem.

Comment: Also, I've confirmed that if you have a Read Only user access key and you do a POST to the /users endpoint (not a GET, like you're supposed to) you will get a 401 error

Comment: At this point I think direct email would work better (since I doubt you want to share your token / keys here in public  and that's the next step to debugging this)

Answer (score 0):

Given the failure of my first answer...

Inspect the bearer token you're getting back just to make sure it is being parsed out correctly

Make a new request object for the 2nd request e.g.

```
$ch2 = curl_init('api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users'); 

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($bearer_token));
```

Since you're reusing the first request, it might still be set to do a POST (that 2nd endpoint is a GET) and might be cluttered with other options left over from that first request.

Comment: Try doing a GET operation on the users endpoint - it doesn't support POST (unless it's to modify a user, in which case the syntax is different and you have to be using credentials that allow read/write access)

Comment: Please read the initial post carefully!! I have mentioned that neither GET nor POST requests work. I have Manage Users permission on the api credentials.....and my commands work fine from the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

This causes your problems

```
if(!curl_exec($ch)){
   die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}
```

you are using curl_exec twice!